# Determine distance between two polygon with having unique id

Tags: arcgis-10.6, calculate-values, mean-shift

I have two polygon feature class one is Source Data and other is shifted data. I want to calculate how much polygon shifted (distance) using ArcGIS 10.6.

Comment: Can you clarify your question to state which particular GIS software package, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop 10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mesure the shift between two polygons, you need to look at the distance between their centroidsand not the distance between their boundaries.

first, compute the coordinates of the centroids of your polygons in both the source and the shifted feature class with the "calculate geometry" (create empty fields and right click on them).

then join the two tables (original and shifted) based on the id of the polygons.

then add a new field and compute the distance with field calculator. (sqrt( (Xsource-Xshifted)^2 + (ySource-yshifted)^2 ) )

Finally, right-click on this field to have the statistics.

Comment: Thanks it works and if i want to calculate angle between two polygons kindly help me out

Comment: basically atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)), and you should manage the division by zero in a conditionnal statment.

Comment: Thanks brother it works